# using mapreduce in R

Tags: r, rmongodb

I am trying to do a mapreduce using R. There is an R package called mapReduce but its functionality was not for complex mapreduce applications.
I am using mongodb for my datatbase and  use R's rmongodb package to access it.Now if U need to do some mapredece, Does anybody know a good R package?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at RHadoop (http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/09/mapreduce-hadoop-r.html). 
Maybe that has a bit more to offer ...

Greetings

Comment: Yes, they have a mapreduce but one needs to have hadoop and HDFS installed in order for it to work.